# Bone won't bend in quadruped leg

Tags: armature, inverse-kinematics

So I am rigging a fox mesh, and the method I used of inverse kinematics isn't working like it has on numerous quadrupeds I have rigged. So the leg has four bones in it. Now I put the IK on the second bone to the bottom, and set the chain length to three. Problem is the top two bones won't bend when manipulated but stay in the bend then started in even when I move target. But I did the same thing with the front leg and it works fine I can't find any differences. I have seen many complaints about this happening after setting a pole target but I haven't yet and its still happening, any ideas?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here you go [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5267" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5267/) It's the back leg, the joint on the top two bones won't bend, with the IK

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about what you're expecting from your rear leg, perhaps bend a bit the two top bones in Edit mode to get what you want? Could you please make a drawing that explains what your leg is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured it out, moonboots you were right I did need to bend the top bones more in edit mode. At first I couldn't figure out how to position them so it worked but still fit the mesh. Then I found a drawing of a fox with an internal skeleton shown along with the body. This showed me I had the two top bones in the back leg positioned wrong, so I changed it to mimic the drawing and it worked. The bones finally bend when using IK. I guess this is just further evidence that nature knows exactly what it is doing with designing of living creatures. lol